# Disabling a Visual Studio project for building using cmake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I'm generating a VS2010 solution with a few projects (currently 4, will be up to 10-20 in the end). I only want one of them to build; the rest should be disabled. I can do this manually by going into the configuration manager and unchecking the boxes I don't want, but obviously this isn't a good solution.

Is there something I can add to the CMakeLists.txt file for a project that will cause it to do this? Searching through the docs, google and SO yielded nothing.

[image: only bam projectshould be built]

Update: Here is my root CMakeLists.txt in case that helps:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_definitions(-DCOMPILER_MSVC)
project (PDEngine)

set(LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

add_subdirectory (units/platform)
add_subdirectory (units/render_api)
add_subdirectory (units/memory)
add_subdirectory (units/game)

set(custom_exe "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/units/Platform/Debug/Platform.lib2")

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${custom_exe}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/local/msvc/bam.bat -j $ENV{NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/local/msvc/bam.bat
)
#add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${custom_exe_clean}
  #COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/local/msvc/bam.bat -c
  #DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/local/msvc/bam.bat
#)

add_custom_target(bam ALL DEPENDS ${custom_exe})
#add_custom_target(bamclean ALL DEPENDS ${custom_exe_clean}})
```

(The bam.bat stuff is based off of the answer I got here: [How do I configure CMake to make the VS solution use a specific build commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866083/how-do-i-configure-cmake-to-make-the-vs-solution-use-a-specific-build-commandlin) )

And here's the CMakeLists.txt for the "platform" project:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Platform)

set (COMPILER_MSVC 1)

include_directories(${Platform_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
file(GLOB Project_HEADERS ${Platform_SOURCE_DIR}/include/platform/*.h)
source_group("Headers" FILES ${Project_HEADERS})

add_library(Platform STATIC EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL src/*.cpp ${Project_HEADERS})
```

Comment: Ah, saw the popup-text for what the voting should mean when I hovered over the vote buttons. "does not show research effort"? I've spent quite a few hours looking into this, and I said so in the post. And "it is unclear" - how is it not clear what I wish to do? "Not useful"? It is to me.

Comment: +1'd you. I agree nothing wrong with this question. Although, you might add some sample sections from your CMakeLists.txt file to give others a context in which to operate.

Comment: I am also interested in this.  I have some custom targets that do static analysis that I only want to run manually, not part of a (ctrl-alt) F7 initiated build.

Answer (score 3):

So if what you want to do is not build something by default, you can remove it from the "ALL" target (which shows up in Visual Studio as ALL_BUILD).  The way you do this is with the target property [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt%3aEXCLUDE_FROM_ALL), or by passing EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL to add_executable and add_library.  (Custom targets default to EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL, so there, to do the reverse, you add ALL to the arguments to add_custom_target).

Then, all your targets will show up, but when clicking "build solution", only the ones you want will build. Others can be built by right clicking them and choosing "Build", like the built-in INSTALL project/target.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't help. If I make a modification, then right click and build "bam" manually, then do a solution build, it'll still build the project in which I made the change. I've updated my post with my CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Custom targets will not be dependencies of ALL_BUILD by default, but they will still be built by a (Re)build Solution command unless unmarked in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD` target property for that purpose.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911387/594456.