# How to build only one target for dependency?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I want to build an application under Windows using CMake + Visual Studio with a lot of dependencies, such as `zlib`. All of them are static libraries.

I've tried `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` and this works pretty well but instead of building only depending target `(zlibstatic)` it builds all of them.

How to remove unused targets (with their solutions) or choose only one?
Mainly I'm searching for feature to define only needed targets.

Part of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/zlib")
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(MyProject PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/zlib")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProject zlibstatic)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a generic way for disabling executable targets in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874702/is-there-a-generic-way-for-disabling-executable-targets-in-cmake)

Comment: @Fred, this helps a bit. Now it doesn't build targets, that I don't want, but their solutions still placed near MyProject. Also it is not elegant solution since you need write every target you don't want to build. Mainly I'm searching for feature to define only needed targets, not disabling unneeded.

Comment: According to this [zlib mirror](https://github.com/luvit/zlib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) there are only 2 targets - the shared and the static library. If you're open to editing zlib's CMakeLists.txt you could just remove parts which you aren't interested in.

Comment: @SteveLorimer I still want to keep all dependencies up-to-date. So, changing each `CMakeLists.txt` for every dependency every time it updates is very uncomfortable.

Comment: @kerrytazi each to their own - at #work we have our own `CMakeLists.txt` file for every 3rd party dependency we pull in (~40 in total). We do this mostly because we want to control the compiler options for our dependencies. In my experience it is not uncomfortable to maintain at all. YMMV of course

Comment: @kerrytazi [this](https://github.com/skebanga/cmake_test) very closely resembles our current build system. (I made the linked project when I was teaching myself cmake in order to migrate our previous build system.) It has an example of a 3rd-party dep in it where we use the same build flags which the rest of our source is built with

Comment: You might want to look into [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). Here is [an example usage](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/external/zlib.cmake) from tensorflow

Comment: @kerrytazi There isn't an opposite to add_library() that I know of.  So once add_library() is issued it will create a project for that target.  Nor is there a way to skip an add_library() command that is always issued.  Some libraries are setup to build static or dynamic libraries or have variables to disable non-required targets.  But that depends upon each libraries `CMakeLists.txt` file.  If you don't want to clutter your build directory you can change the build directory for the other projects to something else.  But again that doesn't quite accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it.

```
MyProject
├───build  <- here I call cmake
├───deps
│   └───zlib
│       └───CMakeLists.txt
├───inc
├───src
└───CMakeLists.txt
```

```
# Include project but remove all tartgets
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/zlib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# Use only specific one target
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(MyProject zlibstatic)

# Include dirs from zlib source directory and from output directory becuse it generates some headers
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(MyProject PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/zlib
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zlib
)

# Just to create beautiful structure in project tree
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET zlibstatic PROPERTY FOLDER Deps)

# Link after all
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProject zlibstatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use vcpkg or conan instead to resolve your dependent library issue this is much cleaner and works well except for header only libraries.

You can of cause do that manually but than you loose the nice cmake setup.